# Enter a child node to get required information to enter another child node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the autoId that is written within the alert child node and turn this into a string in order to grab this autoId from the questions node to get the info inside it  - my code runs but doesn't print/work

(the current user autoId is the first child of the alert node, and the userId is the string that comes from "objectId"/second child of questions). This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var statementAnswered: UILabel
@IBOutlet weak var number1Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var number2Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var number3Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var number4Label: UIButton!

 guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
 let ref = Database.database().reference()

    //enter alert node to get the new Id under the current user node
    let userRef = ref.child("alert").child(currentUser)
    userRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let uniqueKey = snapshot.key
        print(uniqueKey)
        guard let senderDetails = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "from").value as? String else { return }
        guard let userID = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "objectID").value as? String else { return }
        print(senderDetails)
        print(userID)

        let questionNotification = ref.child("questions").child(senderDetails).child(userID)
        questionNotification.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let statement = value?["statement"] as! String
            let number1 = value?["number 1"] as! String
            let number2 = value?["number 2"] as! String
            let number3 = value?["number 3"] as! String
            let number4 = value?["number 4"] as! String
            print(statement)
            print(number1)
            print(number2)
            print(number3)
            print(number4)

            self.statementAnswered.text = question
            self.number1Label.setTitle(number1, for: .normal)
            self.number2Label.setTitle(number2, for: .normal)
            self.number3Label.setTitle(number3, for: .normal)
            self.number4Label.setTitle(number4, for: .normal)
        })
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Here is a snippet of the JSON structure:

```
 "alert" : {
    "FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2" : {
      "-La2uIRfXs15WP8bEfQo" : {
        "from" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2",
        "objectId" : "-La2uIRPzNXnamX4QLER",
        "timestamp" : 1552696293
      }
    }
  },
  "questions" : {
    "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2" : {
      "-La2uIRPzNXnamX4QLER" : {
        "number 1" : "4444",
        "number 2" : "1111",
        "number 3" : "2222",
        "number 4" : "3333",
        "statement" : "favourite number",
        "selected" : "FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2"
      }
    }
  },
```

Appreciate any help!

UPDATE:

I've updated the code and on the console it prints the following (autoId's of users on the app):

```
[Snap (CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3) 1, Snap 
(FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2) 1, Snap (FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2) 
1, Snap (PqMkClaPM3W8k7ZSgzAHb3yne5D3) 1]
[Snap (CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3) 1, Snap 
(FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2) 1, Snap (FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2) 
1, Snap (PqMkClaPM3W8k7ZSgzAHb3yne5D3) 1]
[Snap (CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3) 1, Snap 
(FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2) 1, Snap (FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2) 
1, Snap (PqMkClaPM3W8k7ZSgzAHb3yne5D3) 1]
```

(i'll keep trying to make my breakpoints work in order to see what's wrong and update it here if it works)

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I've changed the structure of the database so that the "questions" don't get saved under the autoId of the currentUser (person answering questions) and instead it's just the random Id that is created and it works although i don't think its the most efficient way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

**Problem1:**

> userRef.child(uniqueKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot })

There is no need to observe user reference again as you are already getting information that you need from observing Alert node.

**Problem2:**

> let questionNotification = self.ref.child("questions").child(senderDetails).child(**self.userId**)

On this line you reference userID to `self`. Looking at your JSON it is obvious that this field will be dynamic so delcaring it globally would not be wise.

**Warning:**

You need to work on naming convention. You are assigning variable names that are not even close to JSON response you are receiving. When your project will get bigger, should you face any error, you will have hard time finding issues as you won't be sure which field is causing it. Also, look at `Codable` protocol. It will make your life easier for encoding and decoding JSON objects.

**Solution:**

```
guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    //enter alert node to get the new Id under the current user node
    let userRef = ref.child("alert").child(currentUser)
    userRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let uniqueKey = snapshot.key
        print(uniqueKey)
        guard let senderDetails = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "from").value as? String else { return }
        guard let userID = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "objectID").value as? String else { return }
        print(senderDetails)
        print(userID)

        let questionNotification = ref.child("questions").child(senderDetails).child(userID)
        questionNotification.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let statement = value?["statement"] as! String
            let number1 = value?["number 1"] as! String
            let number2 = value?["number 2"] as! String
            print(statement)
            print(number1)
            print(number2)
        })
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation! It still doesn't seem to be working, i’m trying to get the statement, number1 and number2 to show on a label and 2 buttons when it runs but they are still blank (i’ve added an update on the code) - would it be better to use an observe .value instead of a childAdded event when grabbing the userId?

Comment: First, I've two questions: 1. Are you able to print data? 2.  Is `number1Label`/`number2Label` a `UIButton`?

Comment: No the data still isn't printing and yes they are buttons but i've disabled them with number1Label.isEnabled = false and number2Label.isEnabled = false :)

Comment: Try adding breakpoints to each line where you are printing and let me know which line doesn't execute. Also, If you haven't already, please copy my code as it is for testing and then make modifications. Make sure `currenUser` is not nil.

Comment: My breakpoints don't seem to be working for some reason but i've noticed that the uniqueKey isn't being called anywhere apart from print? Also, I have copied your code now and something is printing but i'm not quite sure how to link it - i'll update my code above to make it clear

Comment: Just checked your edit and I believe it is because you have more than one senders under user node under `Alerts`. You will have to iterate through all the senders and fetch question based on your requirement. What exactly is your requirement here? I need to know more in order to help you. Also, add screenshot of your current Firebase structure in question.

Comment: The alerts are organised by user node (id of user that the info gets sent to) and within them there are auto Id's which store the alert info (similar to when you receive a notification on instagram activity tab). Originally, I had the firebase structure (above) where the questions are stored under the autoId of the user who answered the questions (e.g. when you like/comment on a post on instagram before it gets sent to the other person as a notification). Now, I updated the firebase structure for the "questions" so that it is just new question auto Id (without being stored under any user Id)

Comment: So my main issue was, once i access the alert node and the user node - I don't know how to get the new alert information Id in order to get the "from" info to use that to access the correct user within the "questions" node so that I can present that information when i run the app. If I iterate through all the senders, wouldn't that take a long time when scaling? Thank you and please let me know if there is anything else i've missed :)